# Getting the name of a type of generic property of class definition using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a class defined as below:

```
class Derived
{
    public int t { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the `System.Type` for every property of the class. This is what I have currently:

```
var properties = node.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();

var symbolDisplayFormat = new SymbolDisplayFormat(
    typeQualificationStyle: SymbolDisplayTypeQualificationStyle.NameAndContainingTypesAndNamespaces
);

foreach (var property in properties) 
{
    var typeSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(property.Type).Symbol as INamedTypeSymbol;
    string name = typeSymbol.ToDisplayString(symbolDisplayFormat);
}
```

Where node is a `ClassDeclarationSyntax`.

This code works fine for the property `t`; the name of the type of the property is returned `System.Int32`. However, for the property `Childs` (it's a type with a generic argument) I get a null `typeSymbol`, which is not the `System.Type` for this property that's expected.

How can I get the type of property of a generic type from a class definition using Roslyn?

Comment: Your `Derived` class doesn't look very derived.

Comment: Yes, I just simplified the class definition. whether is it derived or not derived it is not important for this question.

Comment: `System.Type` is for runtime types; Roslyn has its own type system in `INamedTypeSymbol`.

Comment: What is the runtime type of `context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(property.Type).Symbol`?

Comment: For generic property it is a null. For non- generic property it is a not null. I don't undestand why for generic property is a null?

Comment: I'm sure that you need to try `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo` instead of `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` to retreive `ITypeSymbol`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria, you are right. I have replaced to SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo and it works. Thank you. Answer please and I will mark it.

Comment: where this context come from? How can I declare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo` instead of `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` to retrieve corresponding `ITypeSymbol` from node:

```
...
foreach (var property in properties) 
{
    var info = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(property);
    var typeSymbol = info.Type ?? info.ConvertedType; 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the (first) argument type of a generic, you can use:

```cs
TypeSyntax type = (property.Type as GenericNameSyntax).TypeArgumentList.Arguments[0];
```

Comment: I like this example, thank you for not using `var`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the generic type information with:

```
if (type is INamedTypeSymbol nType) //type is ITypeSymbol
{
    bool isGeneric = nType.IsGenericType;
    int typeArgumentsCount = nType.TypeArguments.Count();
    ...
}
```